# Populate Object from XML

Tags: c#, json, xml, dto, populate

I have an existent object like this:

```
Account account = new Account
{
    Email = "james@example.com",
    Active = true,
    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    Roles = new List<string>
    {
        "User",
        "Admin"
    }
};
```

For updating some properties from a JSON string like

```
string json = @"{
  'Active': false,
  'Roles': [
    'Expired'
  ]
}";
```

i use the method of newtonsoft:

```
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, account);
```

How can i do the same from a XML string?

```
<Account>
    <Active>false</Active>    
</Account>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `XmlSerializer` API has no inbuilt "merge" functionality, however: it *does* support the `*Specified` pattern - meaning: if you have:

```
public string Email { get; set; }
[XmlIgnore]
public bool EmailSpecified { get; set; }
```

then `EmailSpecified` a: controls whether `Email` gets serialized, and b: it is *assigned* a value of `true` when deserialized from an active value. So: you can do something like:

```cs
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool EmailSpecified { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool ActiveSpecified { get; set; }
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool RolesSpecified { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool CreatedDateSpecified { get; set; }
}
```

and then merge manually:

```cs
Account account = new Account
{
    Email = "james@example.com",
    Active = true,
    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    Roles = new List<string>
    {
        "User",
        "Admin"
    }
};

var xml = @"<Account>
<Active>false</Active>
</Account>";
using (var source = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Account));
    var merge = (Account)serializer.Deserialize(source);

    // this bit could also be done via reflection
    if (merge.ActiveSpecified)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Merging " + nameof(merge.Active));
        account.Active = merge.Active;
    }
    if (merge.EmailSpecified)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Merging " + nameof(merge.Email));
        account.Email = merge.Email;
    }
    if (merge.CreatedDateSpecified)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Merging " + nameof(merge.CreatedDate));
        account.CreatedDate = merge.CreatedDate;
    }
    if (merge.RolesSpecified)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Merging " + nameof(merge.Roles));
        account.Roles = merge.Roles;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method creates a new Object. I need populate an existing object with XML like

Comment: @LucaRomagnoli see last paragraph; what you're looking for is a merge API, but that isn't inbuilt. I have an idea on how to make it more manageable, though... one moment...

Comment: @LucaRomagnoli see edit; I think that should get you sorted